# Will iOS ever play nice with Amazon purchased content?

Tags: ios, aws

Are there any indications that I will be able to use my Amazon content on an iPad?

I have songs and videos with Amazon, and I would rather buy an iPad to watch/listen to them.

But I am being forced to get a Kindle Fire instead.

Comment: We can't predict the future or speak for Apple's plans. Please take a look at the [FAQs](http://apple.stackexchange.com/faq) for more info. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there aren't any signs that this will happen anytime soon.  Especially with Apple's In-App Purchase rules.